# Is there any way to get the screen size of the display, regardless of the inspect element tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scenario, where I am making a div and I want to pass the height/width of the innerScreen. I can use the window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
But if the user has opened the inspect tab, then the screen size would decreased which would result in a smaller div. And when the dev tools would be closed the div will not be the size of the actual screen and also I cannot change the div width/height afterwards.

I just want the actual innerHeight and innerWidth, even if the user has already opened the inspect tab, and also i cannot use any package as I am using pug with node
And i cannot add the outer height/width too as it will result in a scroll bar and the client dont want that.

I tried almost everything but I couldn't figure out what to do, nor did I found any solution.

Comment: Very confused why you can't "change the div width/height afterwards." but if you're just trying to make the div the full screen you could `height: 100vh; width: 100vw;` Otherwise, your best bet is `window.outerHeight` and `window.outerWidth`, but `outerHeight` will include the address and bookmark bars.

Comment: I just told you my scenerio, div have to be the same for all the displays, we cant have scrollbar it is the requirement. If the inspect tab is opened and even the height is 100vh it would still result in a smaller div, secondly i cant use css properties too. I have to pass the hieght and width in only numbers

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Window : resize` event would help you out a lot. You can add an event listener and then then recalculate the height/widths you need even if the user opens the inspector. There are some good examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

This is a basic example you could use that I think solves your problem.

```
    // Find your div with id=foo
    const foo = document.querySelector('#foo');
    // Listen for the resize event
    window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => { 
       // If your div exists on this page
       if(foo !== null){
          // Call the resizer function to resize your div
          resizer(foo, 'px', 50); 
       }else{
           // Otherwise handle error
          console.log('Element not found'); 
       }
    });

    // Func takes the div element, size unit (px, % etc) and the offset you want
    const resizer = (element, unit, offset) => {
       const width = window.innerWidth - offset; // Deduct the offset from the window innerWidth
       const height = window.innerHeight - offset; // Deduct the offset from the window innerHeight
       element.style.width = `${width}${unit}`; // Set your div width
       element.style.height = `${height}${unit}`; // Set your div height
   }
```

Comment: But what would the window:resize would do? if the user has already opened up the inspect tab then inner screen would be smaller. And also I do tried the window:resize function and I do have the resize logic implemented but it does not works

Comment: So from reading your response to @AustinEzell it sounds like when your page loads and a user has the inspector tool open the div is smaller and then when the inspector tool is closed the div stays that smaller size? If it is, then it sounds like you are hard coding in your height/width to the div and so you have two options. 1. Use [flex-box](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/interactive-guide-to-flexbox/) to set the css on your classes so that your div flexes with the page or 2. Use `Window : resize` to listen for a page change and dynamically pass the new window size to your div height/width.

Comment: let's say i have added window : resize listener and when the page loads the listener is trigerred, but the thing is that when the page loads div is already created on the previous page, then how to pass the new window with the proper width and height when inspect tab is opened and i dont know what the actual width and height of the screen is. and no i am not hard coding the height and width. I was using window.innerHeight/width but then this issue was pointed by the client.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a simple function and implementation you can use to get started.